# Approximation for $\pi$

Tags: approximation, math-history, pi, golden-ratio

I just stumbled upon

$$ \pi \approx \sqrt{ \frac{9}{5} } + \frac{9}{5} = 3.141640786 $$

which is $\delta = 0.0000481330$  different from $\pi$. Although this is a rather crude approximation I wonder if it has been every used in past times (historically). Note that the above might also be related to the golden ratio $\Phi = \frac{\sqrt 5 + 1}{2} $ somehow (the $\sqrt5$ is common in both).

$$ \Phi = \frac{5}{6} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{9}{5} } + \frac{9}{5} \right) - 1 $$

or

$$ \Phi \approx \frac{5}{6} \pi - 1 $$

I would like to know if someone (known) has used this, or something similar, in their work. Is it at all familiar to any of you?

Related Question ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108510/approximation-of-e-using-pi-and-phi)).

Comment: Another interesting discussion (related) here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108510/approximation-of-e-using-pi-and-phi

Comment: @Artin this first link does not apply because it is an identity formula and not an approximation, and the second link is already included in the original posting.

Comment: What are you expecting, validation of this approximation and some sort of variation of this approximation?

Comment: I look for someone to say, I have seen this and it was used by _x_, or this is related to _y_ approximation.

Comment: The _closest_ approximation for $\pi$ I have found is $$\pi \approx \frac{9}{5}\sqrt{3}$$, which comes from the first term of a series:
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1682189/134791

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ramanujan found this approximation, among many others, according to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiApproximations.html) equation 21 in linked page.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 28):

I have not seen it before.  Note that $\pi = \sqrt{a} + a$ where $a = (1+2\,\pi -\sqrt {1+4\,\pi })/2$, and what you're saying is that a  rational approximation of $a$ is 
$9/5$.  In fact, we have a continued fraction 
$$ a = 1 + \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{3+ \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1139 + \ldots}}}}$$
and $1+1/(1+1/(3+1/1)) = 9/5$.  The fact that the first omitted element, $1139$, is so large makes this a very good approximation: the error in approximating $a$ by $9/5$ is only about $3.5 \times 10^{-5}$.  Four elements later comes $7574$, so an even better approximation is $1+1/(1+1/(3+1/(1+1/(1139+1/(1+1/(15+1/1)))))) = 174530/96963$ with error about $1.4 \times 10^{-14}$.

EDIT: Perhaps even more remarkable are 
$$ \eqalign{\pi - \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{47}{35} \pi} &\approx \dfrac{6}{7}\cr
\pi - \sqrt{\dfrac{3}{5} + \dfrac{5}{2} \pi } &\approx \dfrac{216}{923}\cr}$$

corresponding to the continued fractions

$$ \eqalign{\pi - \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{47}{35} \pi} &= \dfrac{1}{1+ \dfrac{1}{6 + \dfrac{1}{126402+ \ldots}}}\cr
\pi - \sqrt{\dfrac{3}{5} + \dfrac{5}{2} \pi} &= 
\dfrac{1}{4+\dfrac{1}{3+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{19+\dfrac{1}{133286+\ldots}}}}}}}\cr}$$

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but it may be useful.

The largest root of the simple polynomial
$$x^2-3x+1$$

is 
$$\Phi^2=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2=\Phi+1$$

Modifying the coefficients of the polynomial using $5$ and $6$ it becomes

$$5^2x^2-5\times6\times 3 x+6^2$$

and its largest root is this approximation to $\pi$.

$$\pi\approx \frac{6}{5}\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)=\frac{9}{5}+\sqrt{\frac{9}{5}}$$

This procedure seems related to the one for [another approximation by Ramanujan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1723358/134791).

Comment: Where did the negative sign of $-3x$ go?

Comment: @ja72 Corrected, thank you!