# Prove this inequality $ \sqrt{5} > \frac {13 + 4\pi}{24 - 4\pi} $

Tags: inequality, approximation, pi

$$ \sqrt{5} > \frac {13 + 4\pi}{24 -  4\pi} $$

Comment: @Simon S: I've tried [The one by (published by Nilakantha in the 15th century)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Infinite_series). Other than calculators, all techniques are permitted. I'm looking for the best / shortest solution.

Comment: Nice almost integer!
From the observation by @JackDAurizio,
$$\frac{\left(133-37\sqrt{5}\right)}{\pi}\approx 16.0000007560086$$

Maybe this interesting question could be reopened by adding as a context two other approximations to $\pi$ that use $\sqrt{5}$, such as 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092215/how-was-this-approximation-of-pi-involving-sqrt5-arrived-at and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146831/approximation-for-pi

Comment: The rational multiple of $\frac{1}{\pi}$ can be related to two convergents to $\pi$:
$$\frac{133}{\pi}=\frac{111}{\pi}+\frac{22}{\pi}\approx \frac{106}{3}+7=\frac{127}{3}=\frac{2^7-1}{3}$$

Answer (score 6):

This is the same as proving that
$$\frac{1}{16}(133-37\sqrt{5})>\pi$$
and it follows from the fact that the continued fraction of the LHS is:
$$ [3;7,15,1,660,\ldots] $$
while the continued fraction of $\pi$ is:
$$ [3;7,15,1,292,\ldots].$$