# Finding the summation of this peculiar type of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-integration, geometric-progressions

> Find $\Sigma_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a+\frac{b^{r}}{r}}$ where $b>1$ and $a$ is a positive real number.

I guess that this sum must be convergent as the terms gets smaller, but I have no idea on where to start on.

I tried using differentiation of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ as a geometric progression, but that lead me nowhere. I have also learnt that definite integrals can be represented as limits of infinite sums.

Can I use a definite integral to evaluate this summation as a Riemann summation? Is there a closed form for this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't the series diverge since $\frac1{a+b^r/r}\to\frac1a>0$ as $r\to\infty$? The successive terms need to approach $0$ for the sum to converge; merely decreasing isn't sufficient.

Comment: It [converges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2F%28e%2Bkhinchin%5En%2Fn%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C300%7D%5D) for some values and the $b=2,a=1$ case has [no closed form found](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B1%2F%281%2B2%5En%2Fn%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D). You could get an integral representation

Comment: @Phobo Havuz How does this diverge? If b> 1, b^r/r tends to infinity and the terms tend to 0.

Comment: Oops yeah you're right, it does converge for some $b>1$. Please ignore my previous comment

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Could you give an idea about  a possible integral representation ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Not much has helped, but the sum is almost like one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323333/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-fracn3n-1?noredirect=1). Do you have any ideas?