# Is there a way to show $\frac{1646-736\sqrt{5}}{2641-1181\sqrt{5}}=\frac{17+15\sqrt{5}}{7+15\sqrt{5}}$ without multiplying large numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to show that the following equality holds $$\frac{1646-736\sqrt{5}} {2641-1181\sqrt{5}} =\frac{17+15\sqrt{5}} {7+15\sqrt{5}} $$ The only way I could prove it was via cross multiplication using a calculator.

Is there any simpler way to do this? Following prime factorization is given $$1646=2\times 823,736=2^5\times 23,2641=19\times 139$$ and $1181$ is prime. I strictly want to avoid multiplying large numbers. I don't know if that's possible here.

The above simplification is used to obtain [a famous approximation to $\pi$ given by Ramanujan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2285072/72031).

Comment: I would see what happens when you rationalize the denominators by multiplying by the conjugates. You'd still have to multiply four digit numbers.

Comment: @EthanBolker: this is related to a key result of Ramanujan. I really wonder how he figured out that it was possible to simplify the expression.

Comment: how large is large?

Comment: @dezdichado: well that's subjective. I wish not to generate any numbers of 6 or more digits.

Comment: for one thing $\dfrac{2641}{1181}\approx \sqrt{5}\approx\dfrac{1646}{736}$ as far as eyeballing concerned. Besides, even if you cross multiply, you would not $6$ digits it looks like. Otherwise, I would just stick to the good old undetermined coefficient method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1646-736\sqrt{5}} {2641-1181\sqrt{5}} =1 -5\frac{199-89\sqrt{5}}{2641-1181\sqrt{5}}
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{89\sqrt{5}-199}{2641-1181\sqrt{5}}=\frac{2}{7+15 \sqrt{5}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I would have never been able to think of it. +1

Comment: How is the second equality proved? Cross product?

Comment: Your answer will be linked in an update of one of my answers dealing with Ramanujan's formula. I will add a link to that in current question after sometime.

Comment: @AndreaMarino That's right ... there is still some sizable numerical calculation ... but it is less bad.

Comment: The fact that difference of numerator and denominator is divisible by $5$ never crossed my mind even though it is obvious once mentioned. This is another example which only proves "simplicity eludes us".

Answer (score 2):

There is another approach which is more in line with the answer linked in the question.

Let $\phi=(1+\sqrt {5})/2$ denote the golden ratio so that $\sqrt{5}=2\phi-1$ and $$\phi^2=\phi+1\tag{1}$$ The fraction in question can now be written as $$\frac{1191-736\phi}{1911-1181\phi}\tag{2} $$ Let us observe that $$ \frac{a-b\phi} {c-d\phi} =\frac{b\phi^2-a\phi}{d\phi^2-c\phi}=\frac{b-(a-b)\phi}{d-(c-d)\phi}\tag{3}$$ and apply this to $(2)$ repeatedly. We get the following sequence of fractions $$\frac{736-455\phi}{1181-730\phi}, \\ \frac{455-281\phi}{730-451\phi},\\ \frac{281-174\phi}{451-279\phi},\\ \frac{174-107\phi}{279-172\phi},\\ \frac{107-67\phi}{172-107\phi},\\ \frac{67-40\phi}{107-65\phi},\\ \frac{40-27\phi}{65-42\phi},\\ \frac{27-13\phi}{42-23\phi},\\ \frac{13-14\phi}{23-19\phi},\\ \frac{14-(-1)\phi}{19-4\phi},\\ \frac{-1-15\phi}{4-15\phi} $$ The last fraction equals $$\frac{15\phi+1}{15\phi-4}=\frac{30\phi+2}{30\phi-8}=\frac{17+15\sqrt{5}}{7+15\sqrt{5}}$$ The application of $(3)$ was stopped at a point when the numbers in the fraction were least in absolute value. Any further application would have led to larger numbers. This approach has advantage that we don't need to know beforehand the final simple answer.

---

If we have a fraction like $$\frac {a+b\phi} {c+d\phi} $$ then we can use the transformation $$\frac{a+b\phi} {c+d\phi} =\frac{a/\phi+b} {c/\phi+d} =\frac{a(\phi-1)+b}{c(\phi-1)+d}=\frac{b-a+a\phi}{d-c+c\phi}$$ and hope to get an expression with small numbers.

Comment: very good!!!!~~