# Why do ratios of these Fibonacci-type sequences approach $\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, pi

Define $A_n$ by $A_1=12$, $A_2=18$, and $A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$ for $n\ge3$. Similarly define $B_n$ by $B_1=5$, $B_2=5$, and $B_n=B_{n-1}+B_{n-2}$ for $n\ge3$.

Terms of $A_n$: $12, 18, 30, 48, 78,\dots$

Terms of $B_n$: $5, 5, 10, 15, 25,\dots$

I found that dividing element $A_n$ by $B_n$ where $n$ approaches $\infty$ appears to result in:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left ( \frac{A_n}{B_n} \right ) = \pi$$

My question is, why does the ratio appear to converge towards $\pi$, and what is the significance of $5, 12, 18$ as to why this happens?

Comment: As pointed out by Michael, the correct limit is $$L =\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left ( \frac{A_n}{B_n} \right ) = \frac{6\phi^2}{5} = 3.14164078\dots$$ No wonder it looked familiar -- this approximation for $\pi$ was already found by ***Ramanujan*** and expressed as, $$L = \sqrt{\frac{9}{5}}+\frac{9}{5} = 3.14164078\dots$$ See this related [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146831/approximation-for-pi).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct ratio is $\frac{6\phi^2}5=3.14164079$, which is remarkably close to $\pi$.  The $6/5$ comes because the starting values are $6,6$ in one and $5,5$ in the other.  The $\phi^2$ comes because the sequences are shifted two steps from each other - both 6's appear before the 5's.

Comment: "remarkably close" is a coincidence?  (Or as close to a coincidence as math allows anything to be?)

Comment: I don't agree with your numerical result. The convergence is to $3.1416407865$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust is right.... $6\phi^2 / 5 \approx 3.14164079.$  Still remarkably close to $\pi$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, it looks like Michael rounded $\phi$ to $1.618$ for the opening calculation.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake.  Fixed now.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: yep, remarkably close to $3.14$.

Answer (score 4):

Recurrences of the form

$$T_n=T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}$$ are linear and known to have a general solution of the form $$T_n=C_0z_0^n+C_1z_1^n,$$ where $z_0,z_1$ are the roots of the "characteristic equation", $z^2=z+1$.

By the usual formulas,

$$z_0,z_1=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2.$$
Using the initial conditions,

$$T_0=C_0+C_1,\\T_1=C_0z_0+C_1z_1.$$

As $|z_0|>|z_1|$, the first term quickly dominates and

$$T_n\approx\frac{T_1-z_1T_0}{z_0-z_1}z_0^n.$$

In your case, for large $n$,

$$\frac{A_n}{B_n}\approx\frac{A_1-z_1A_0}{B_1-z_1B_0}=\frac{3\sqrt5+9}5=3.1416407864999\cdots$$

Comment: +1 This close approximation was already known to Ramanujan and expressed by him as, $$\frac{3\sqrt{5}+9}{5} = \sqrt{\frac{9}{5}}+\frac{9}{5}$$ Just another example of his mathematical aesthetics. Kindly see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146831/approximation-for-pi).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: it turns out that the solution of $\sqrt x+x=\pi$ is $1.7999649350783\cdots$. The next rational approximation of this number isn't so nice: $10267/5704$, giving only $8$ correct decimals.