# Integrals of the form ${\large\int}_0^\infty\operatorname{arccot}(x)\cdot\operatorname{arccot}(a\,x)\cdot\operatorname{arccot}(b\,x)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, logarithms

I'm interested in integrals of the form
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty\operatorname{arccot}(x)\cdot\operatorname{arccot}(a\,x)\cdot\operatorname{arccot}(b\,x)\ dx,\color{#808080}{\text{ for }a>0,\,b>0}\tag1$$
It's known$\require{action}\require{enclose}\texttip{{}^\dagger}{Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, 7th edition, page 599, (4.511)}$ that
$$I(a,0)=\frac{\pi^2}4\left[\ln\left(1+\frac1a\right)+\frac{\ln(1+a)}a\right].\tag2$$
*Maple* and *Mathematica* are also able to evaluate
$$I(1,1)=\frac{3\pi^2}4\ln2-\frac{21}8\zeta(3).\tag3$$

---

Is it possible to find a general closed form for $I(a,1)$? Or, at least, for $I(2,1)$ or $I(3,1)$?

Comment: When is the book coming out? ;)

Comment: i would try the following: introduce an additional parameter $c$ in the first $\text{arccot}$ and then differentiate w.r.t to all three paramaters. The resulting integral should be doable. Then integrating back and see how far you get staying as general eas possible. I'm somehow expecting that we end up with a quite ugly combinations of dilogarithms.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I finally managed to find a general solution to this problem. Although I put a lot of effort into simplification of the result, it is still not as pretty and symmetric as I would like it to be. I hope to improve it later. Sorry for poor typesetting.

Assuming $0<a<b<c,$
$$\int_0^\infty\operatorname{arccot}(ax)\,\operatorname{arccot}(bx)\,\operatorname{arccot}(cx)\,dx=\\
\frac1{24 a b c}\left(2 a (b+2 c) \ln ^3(a)-3 \left(2 b (a+c) \ln (b)+(4 a c-2 b c) \ln (c)+\\
b \left(-2 c \operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)+(c-a) \ln
   (c-a)-(a+c) \ln (a+c)+a \ln \left(c^2-b^2\right)\right)\right) \ln ^2(a)\\
+3 \left(b c \left(\ln ^2(b)+2 \left(2 \ln (a+c)+\ln
   \left(-\frac{c (b+c)}{(a-b) (a-c) (b-c)}\right)\right) \ln (b)+\ln ^2(b-a)\\
-3 \ln ^2(c)+\ln ^2(c-a)-\ln ^2(c-b)+\ln ^2(b+c)-4 \operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{a}{c}\right) \ln (a+b)+\\
2 \ln (b-a) \ln \left(\frac{c}{c-a}\right)-6 \ln (c) \ln (a+c)+2 \ln (a+c) \ln (c-b)\\
+4 \ln (c)
   (\ln (c-a)+\ln (c-b))-4 \ln (c) \ln (b+c)-2 \ln (c-a) \ln (b+c)\right)\\
+a \left(b \left(2 \ln ^2(b)-2 \ln
   \left(\frac{a^2-c^2}{b^2-c^2}\right) \ln (b)+\ln ^2(a+b)-\ln ^2(c-a)-\ln ^2(a+c)\\
-3 \ln ^2(b+c)-2 \ln (b-a) \ln (c-b)+2 \ln (c-a) (\ln
   (b-a)+\ln (b+c))\\
+2 \ln (a+b) \ln \left(\frac{b+c}{c^2-a^2}\right)+2 \ln (a+c) \ln \left(c^2-b^2\right)\right)-c \left(\ln ^2(b)-2 (\ln
   ((b-a) c)-\ln (a+c)) \ln (b)+\ln ^2(b-a)+\ln ^2(a+b)\\
-3 \ln ^2(c)+\ln ^2(a+c)+\ln ^2(c-b)+2 \ln ^2(b+c)+2 \ln (b-a) \ln
   \left(\frac{c}{c-b}\right)\\
-2 \ln (a+b) \ln (b+c)-2 \ln (a+c) \ln (c (b+c))\right)\right)\right) \ln (a)\\
-2 (a (b-c)+b c) \ln ^3(b)+a c \ln
   ^3(b-a)-b c \ln ^3(b-a)-3 a c \ln ^3(c)+5 b c \ln ^3(c)\\
+2 a b \ln ^3(c-a)-2 b c \ln ^3(c-a)+2 a c \ln ^3(a+c)-2 b c \ln ^3(a+c)-a b \ln
   ^3(c-b)\\
-b c \ln ^3(c-b)-a b \ln ^3(b+c)-3 b c \ln ^3(b+c)-3 b c \ln (b-a) \ln ^2(c)\\
-3 a b \ln ((a-b) (b-c)) \ln ^2(c-a)+3 b c \ln ((a-b)
   (b-c)) \ln ^2(c-a)\\
+3 b c \ln \left(\left(b^2-a^2\right) c\right) \ln ^2(a+c)-3 a c \ln (a+b) \ln ^2(c-b)+3 a c \ln ((b-a) c) \ln
   ^2(c-b)\\
-3 a b (\ln (b-a)-\ln ((a+b) (a+c))) \ln ^2(c-b)+3 b c \ln (c (a+c)) \ln ^2(c-b)\\
-3 a c \ln \left(\frac{b-a}{a+b}\right) \ln
   ^2(b+c)+6 a c \ln (c) \ln ^2(b+c)-12 b c \ln (c) \ln ^2(b+c)\\
+3 a b \ln (a+c) \ln ^2(b+c)+3 b c \left(\ln \left(b^2-a^2\right)+\ln
   (a+c)\right) \ln ^2(b+c)\\
-3 a c \ln ^2(b-a) \ln \left(1-\frac{b}{c}\right)-b c \pi ^2 \left(\ln (b-a)+\ln
   \left(\frac{b-c}{a-c}\right)\right)-5 a c \pi ^2 \ln (c)-5 b c \pi ^2 \ln (c)\\
-3 b c \ln ^2(b-a) \ln \left(-\frac{c}{b-c}\right)-12 b c \ln
   ^2(c) \ln \left(\frac{c-a}{a+c}\right)-12 b c \ln (a+b) \ln (c) \ln \left(\frac{c-a}{a+c}\right)\\
+\pi ^2 a c (\ln (b-a)-\ln (a+c))+3 a b
   \pi ^2 \ln (a+c)+4 b c \pi ^2 \ln (a+c)-6 b c \ln ^2(c) \ln (c-b)\\
+6 a b \ln (b-a) \ln (c-a) \ln (c-b)-6 b c \ln (b-a) \ln (c-a) \ln
   (c-b)\\
-6 a b \ln (a+b) \ln (a+c) \ln (c-b)-6 b c \ln (a+b) \ln (a+c) \ln (c-b)\\
-12 b c \ln (c) \ln (a+c) \ln (c-b)-a b \pi ^2 (\ln
   (c-a)+\ln (c-b))\\
+3 a c \ln ^2(a+b) \ln \left(\frac{c (c-b)}{b+c}\right)+3 a c \ln ^2(c) (\ln (b-a)-\ln (b+c))+9 b c \ln ^2(c) \ln
   (b+c)\\
-6 a c \ln (a+b) \ln (c) \ln (b+c)+6 b c \ln (a+b) \ln (c) \ln (b+c)+12 b c \ln (c) \ln (c-a) \ln (b+c)\\
+5 \pi ^2 a b \ln (b+c)+6
   a c \pi ^2 \ln (b+c)+3 b c \pi ^2 \ln (b+c)-3 a b \ln ^2(a+c) \ln \left(\frac{b+c}{a+b}\right)\\
+6 a c \ln (b-a) \ln (a+c) \ln (c (b+c))-6
   b c \ln (b-a) \ln (a+c) \ln (c (b+c))\\
-3 a c \ln ^2(a+c) (\ln (b-a)+\ln (c (b+c)))-3 b c \ln ^2(a+b) \ln \left(-\frac{c
   (b+c)}{b-c}\right)\\
-3 \ln ^2(b) \left(a \left(c (\ln (b-a)+\ln (c)-2 \ln (a+c)+\ln (b+c))\\
+b \ln
   \left(\frac{b^2-c^2}{a^2-c^2}\right)\right)-b c \ln \left(\frac{(a-b) c (c-b)}{a^2-c^2}\right)\right)-6 a c \ln (b-a) \ln (c) \ln
   \left(c^2-b^2\right)\\
+6 b c \ln (b-a) \ln (c) \ln \left(c^2-b^2\right)\\
-\ln (b) \left(b c \left(3 \left(-\ln ^2(a+b)+2 (\ln ((a+c)
   (b+c))-\ln (c-a)) \ln (a+b)\\
+2 \ln ^2(c)+\ln ^2(c-a)+\ln ^2(a+c)-3 \ln ^2(b+c)-2 \ln (a+c) \ln (c-b)\\
+2 \ln (c-a) \ln (b+c)+2 \ln (c)
   (\ln ((a+c) (b+c))-2 \ln (c-a))\\
-2 \ln (b-a) \ln \left(c^2-a^2\right)+2 \ln (b-a) \ln \left(c^2-b^2\right)\right)+\pi ^2\right)\\
+a \left(c
   \left(6 (\ln (b-a)+\ln (c)-\ln (a+c)) \ln \left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)+\pi ^2\right)\\
+3 b \left(\ln ^2(a+b)+2 \ln
   \left(\frac{b+c}{c^2-a^2}\right) \ln (a+b)-\ln ^2(c-a)-\ln ^2(a+c)-3 \ln ^2(b+c)\\
+2 \ln (b-a) \ln \left(\frac{a-c}{b-c}\right)+2 \ln (c-a)
   \ln (b+c)+2 \ln (a+c) \ln \left(c^2-b^2\right)+2 \pi ^2\right)\right)\right)\\
+6 \left(2 \left(a \ln \left(\frac{a}{c}\right)+b \ln
   \left(\frac{c}{b}\right)\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{c}\right) c+2 \left(a \ln \left(\frac{a}{c}\right)+b \ln
   \left(\frac{c}{b}\right)\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{c}{a}\right) c-2 b \ln \left(\frac{b}{c}\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{b (a+c)}{a
   (b-c)}\right) c+2 b \ln \left(\frac{b}{c}\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{b (a-c)}{a (b+c)}\right) c-2 a \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a}{c}\right) c+2
   b \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{b}{c}\right) c-2 b \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{b}{c}\right) c+2 a \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{c}{a}\right) c-(a-b)
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{(b-a) c}{b (a+c)}\right) c-(a-b) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a (c-b)}{(a-b) c}\right) c+(a+b) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a
   (c-b)}{(a+b) c}\right) c-(a-b) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{b-a}{b+c}\right) c+(a+b) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a+b}{b+c}\right) c-(a+b)
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a (b+c)}{(a+b) c}\right) c+(a-3 b) \zeta (3) c+2 a b \ln \left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+2
   a b \ln \left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)+\left(a b \ln \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+b c \ln
   \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)+a c \ln \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{b-a}{b-c}\right)+\left(a b \ln
   \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+b c \ln \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)+a c \ln \left(\frac{c}{a}\right)\right)
   \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{b-c}{a+b}\right)-\left(a b \ln \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+a c \ln \left(\frac{a}{c}\right)-b c \ln
   \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+b}{b+c}\right)-\left(a b \ln \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+a c \ln
   \left(\frac{a}{c}\right)-b c \ln \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)\right) \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)-2 a b
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+2 a b \operatorname{Li}_3\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)-b (a-c) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a-b}{a-c}\right)-a (b-c)
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{b-a}{b-c}\right)+a (b-c) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a+b}{b-c}\right)-b (a-c) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a (b-c)}{b
   (a-c)}\right)+b (a+c) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a+b}{a+c}\right)+b (a+c) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{b (a+c)}{a (b-c)}\right)+b (a-c)
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{b (a-c)}{a (b+c)}\right)-b (a-c) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{c-a}{b+c}\right)+b (a+c)
   \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}\right)-a (b+c) \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a (b+c)}{b (a+c)}\right)\right)\right)$$

[Here](http://gist.githubusercontent.com/VladimirReshetnikov/f34cd9013a432df47696/raw/9fab5d759698cb7f50e9dc63a3c09cc22d7b28e2/ArcTan.nb) is the equivalent *Mathematica* expression. The formula can be proved using differentiation by parameters $a,b,c.$

In fact, the integrand even has a closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions, dilogarithms and trilogarithms, but it is too large to put it here.

Comment: How much paper did you use to simplify this??

Comment: You may be interested in this paper (especially appendix B): http://homeweb.unifr.ch/kellerha/pub/gafa.pdf . There are a handful of auxiliary functions defined there to denote various sums of polylog terms, which would probably go a long way towards grouping the terms of your ghastly result in a more organized manner. There are also a few general closed forms for certain integrals that may also come in handy. And congratulations on your progress!

Comment: I made some progress on simplification. A draft is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22127/19661).

Comment: It starts looking that the antiderivative itself might be not as scary as it seemed in the beginning. But it needs some more work...

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov are there any values $0<a<b<c$ such that this integral can be expressed in terms of elementary functions only, without $\text{Li}_2$ and $\text{Li}_3$?

Answer (score 58):

By the substitution $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ it is not hard to see that
$$I(\nu^{-1},1)=\int^\infty_0\frac{\arctan^2{x}\arctan(\nu x)}{x^2}{\rm d}x$$

First, start off by re-expressing the integral
\begin{align}
\int^\pi_0x^2\cos(nx)\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\ {\rm d}x
&=-{\rm Re}\int_C\frac{z+1}{z-1}z^{n-1}\ln^2{z}\ {\rm d}z\\
&=(-1)^{n}\int^1_0\frac{1-x}{1+x}x^{n-1}(\ln^2{x}-\pi^2)\ {\rm d}x-\int^1_0\frac{1+x}{1-x}x^{n-1}\ln^2{x}\ {\rm d}x\\
\end{align}
where $C$ is the arc joining $z=1$ to $z=-1$. (The first equality follows from $z=e^{ix}$, whereas the second follows from the fact that the integral along $[-1,\epsilon]\cup\epsilon\exp(i[\pi,0])\cup[\epsilon,1]\cup C$ is $0$ since $z=1$ is a removable singularity and the indent around $z=0$ vanishes.)

Next, note that
\begin{align}
I_\nu(\nu^{-1},1)
&=\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\frac{x^2}{\tan{x}(\cos^2{x}+\nu^2\sin^2{x})}{\rm d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int^\pi_0\frac{x^2}{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)(1+(1-\nu^2)\cos{x}+\nu^2)}{\rm d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{8\nu}\int^\pi_0\left(x^2\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{\nu-1}{\nu+1}\right)^nx^2\cos(nx)\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right){\rm d}x\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4\nu}\ln{2}-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8\nu}-\frac{\xi}{4\nu}\left(\int^1_0\frac{1-x}{(1+x)(1+\xi x)}(\ln^2{x}-\pi^2)+\frac{1+x}{(1-x)(1-\xi x)}\ln^2{x}\ {\rm d}x\right)
\end{align}
Here $\xi=\dfrac{\nu-1}{\nu+1}$. Utilising the partial fraction decompositions
$$\frac{1-x}{(1+x)(1+\xi x)}=\frac{\nu+1}{1+x}-\frac{\nu}{1+\xi x}$$
$$\frac{1+x}{(1-x)(1-\xi x)}=\frac{\nu+1}{1-x}-\frac{\nu}{1-\xi x}$$
in tandem with the easily verifiable fact
$$\int^1_0\frac{\ln^2{x}}{1+\lambda x}{\rm d}x=-\frac{2{\rm Li}_3(-\lambda)}{\lambda}$$
yields
\begin{align}
I_\nu(\nu^{-1},1)
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4\nu}\ln{2}-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8\nu}-\frac{\xi}{4\nu}\left(\frac{\pi^2\nu}{\xi}\ln(1+\xi)-\pi^2(\nu+1)\ln{2}+\frac{7\zeta(3)}{2}(\nu+1)-\frac{4\nu}{\xi}\chi_3(\xi)\right)\\
&=\chi_3\left(\frac{\nu-1}{\nu+1}\right)-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\nu}\right)
\end{align}
where $\displaystyle\chi_s(z)=\sum_{n\ \text{odd}}\frac{z^n}{n^s}=\frac{1}{2}\left({\rm Li}_s(z)-{\rm Li}_s(-z)\right)$ is the Legendre-chi function.

Integrating back,
\begin{align}
I_\nu(\nu^{-1},1)
&=\underbrace{\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln\left(\frac{(1+\nu)^{1+\nu}}{\nu^\nu}\right)-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}\nu}_{\text{Let this be C}}+2\int^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1\frac{\chi_3(v)}{(1+v)^2}{\rm d}v\\
&=C-\left.\frac{2\chi_3(v)}{1+v}\right|^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1+2\int^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1\frac{\chi_2(v)}{v(1+v)}{\rm d}v\\
&=C+(1-\nu)\chi_3\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}-\left.\color{white}{\frac{1}{1}}2\chi_2(v)\ln(1+v)\right|^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1+\int^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1\frac{\ln(1+v)\ln\left(\frac{1+v}{1-v}\right)}{v}{\rm d}v\\
&=C+(1-\nu)\chi_3\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}+2\chi_2\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln{2}\\
&\ \ \ \ +\frac{1}{2}\int^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1\frac{\ln^2(1+v)-\ln^2(1-v)+\ln^2\left(\frac{1-v}{1+v}\right)}{v}{\rm d}v
\end{align}
Repeatedly integrating by parts, it is not hard to derive that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1\frac{\ln^2(1+v)}{v}{\rm d}v
=&\ -\frac{1}{6}\ln^3\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)+\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}-{\rm Li}_3\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)+{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)\\
&\ +\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-\nu}{2}\right)\ln^2\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)\\
-\frac{1}{2}\int^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1\frac{\ln^2(1-v)}{v}{\rm d}v
=&\ {\rm Li}_3\left(\frac{2\nu}{1+\nu}\right)-{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{2\nu}{1+\nu}\right)\ln\left(\frac{2\nu}{1+\nu}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)\ln^2\left(\frac{2\nu}{1+\nu}\right)\\
\frac{1}{2}\int^\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}_1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-v}{1+v}\right)}{v}{\rm d}v
=&\ -2\chi_3(\nu)+2\chi_2(\nu)\ln{\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2\nu\ln\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)
\end{align}
Therefore, we get, for $I(\nu^{-1},1)$,
\begin{align}
I(\nu^{-1},1)
=&\color{brown}{\ (1-\nu)\chi_3\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)-2\chi_3(\nu)+{\rm Li}_3\left(\frac{2\nu}{1+\nu}\right)-{\rm Li}_3\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}\nu}\\
&\ \color{brown}{+2\chi_2(\nu)\ln{\nu}+2\chi_2\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)-{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{2\nu}{1+\nu}\right)\ln\left(\frac{2\nu}{1+\nu}\right)}\\
&\ \color{brown}{+{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln\left(\frac{(1+\nu)^{1+\nu}}{\nu^\nu}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln{2}}\\
&\ \color{brown}{+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2\nu\ln\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-\nu}{2}\right)\ln^2\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{6}\ln^3\left(\frac{1+\nu}{2}\right)}\\
&\ \color{brown}{-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-\nu}{1+\nu}\right)\ln^2\left(\frac{2\nu}{1+\nu}\right)}
\end{align}
If no mistakes were made, this formula should hold for $0<\nu\le1$. Further simplifications to the formula may be possible through some polylogarithm identities.

Comment: nice work (+1). what exactly is the reason for the reformulation in terms of the two auxillary integrals? i would have guessed that one can dig in the orignal integral by more or less the same techniques.

Comment: Bravo!! Very good work!

Comment: Very nice result! +1. By the way, maybe I'm wrong, but in the last expression there is a condition $0 < a \leq 1$, therefore this is a closed-form for $I(c,1)$ for $c \geq 1$.

Comment: @tired Thanks. I have followed your suggestion and simplified the answer.

Comment: @user153012 Thank you. Yes, this should hold for $c\ge 1$. I have not checked if the formula is valid for $0<c<1$ though.

Answer (score 55):

$$\begin{align}I(2,1)&=\frac{\pi^2}3\ln2-\frac{\pi^2}6\ln3+2\ln^22\cdot\ln3-3\ln2\cdot\ln^23+\frac{29}{24}\ln^33\\&+\frac{73}{16}\zeta(3)-2\ln2\cdot\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac13\right)-\frac{13}4\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac13\right)-4\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac23\right)\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}I(3,1)&=\frac{13\,\pi^2}{12}\ln2-\frac{4\,\pi^2}9\ln3-\frac13\ln2\cdot\ln^23+\frac7{18}\ln^33\\&-\frac{13}8\zeta(3)+\ln3\cdot\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\tfrac13\right)+\frac43\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac13\right)-\frac23\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\tfrac23\right)\end{align}$$

---

Update (in response to a comment):
$$\begin{align}&I(\phi,1)=\frac32\ln^32+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\Big[\left(6-3\sqrt5\right)\ln2+\left(3\sqrt5-4\right)\ln\left(1+\sqrt5\right)\Big]+\frac{51-21\sqrt5}{48}\zeta(3)\\&-\frac{\ln\left(1+\sqrt5\right)}2\Bigg[15\ln^22-15\ln\left(1+\sqrt5\right)\ln2+4\ln^2\left(1+\sqrt5\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}4\right)\Bigg]\\&-\ln\left(3+\sqrt5\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\sqrt5-2\right)+\frac{11+3\sqrt5}{48}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(9-4\sqrt5\right)-\frac{13+3\sqrt5}6\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\sqrt5-2\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 25):

Some further raw results (largely inspired by Cleo's answer :+1) for the impatient :

$$I\left(4,1\right)=- \frac{1915}{128}\zeta(3)+\left(\frac {359}{192}\ln(2) + 2\ln(3) + \frac{175}{96}\ln(5)\right)\pi^2 +\frac{513}{32}\ln(2)^2\ln(5) - \frac{1535}{96}\ln(2)^3 - \frac {15}4\ln(3)^3 - \frac{1031}{96}\ln(5)^3 - \frac{31}8\ln(2)\ln(5)^2  + \frac{93}8\ln(3)\ln(5)^2 + \frac {45}4\operatorname{Li}_3(1/3) +\frac{93}8\operatorname{Li}_3(2/3) - \frac{81}{32}\operatorname{Li}_3(1/5)  - \operatorname{Li}_3(2/5) - \frac 38\operatorname{Li}_3(3/5) - \frac {91}{32}\operatorname{Li}_3(4/5)- \frac 38\operatorname{Li}_3(1/6) + \frac 5{16}\operatorname{Li}_3(1/10) \\- \ln(2)\left(12\operatorname{Li}_2(1/3) + 8\operatorname{Li}_2(1/4) + 2\operatorname{Li}_2(1/5)+\frac {163}{16}\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5) + \frac {195}{16}\operatorname{Li}_2(3/5)\right) \\- \frac{189}{16}\,\ln(5)\;(\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5)+\operatorname{Li}_2(3/5))$$

---

$$I\left(5,1\right)=- \frac{577}{160}\zeta(3)+\left(\frac {11}{15}\ln(3) + \frac{191}{480}\ln(4) - \frac{11}{60}\ln(5)\right)\pi^2 + \frac{17}{10}\ln(3)\ln(5)^2 - \frac{17}{30}\ln(3)^3 - \frac{173}{960}\ln(4)^3 - \frac{181}{120}\ln(5)^3  - \frac 1{10}\ln(4)\ln(5)^2 + \frac{51}{160}\ln(4)^2\ln(5) + 2\operatorname{Li}_3(1/3) + \frac 75\operatorname{Li}_3(2/3) - \frac 38\operatorname{Li}_3(1/5) + \frac 9{10}\operatorname{Li}_3(2/5) - \frac 35\operatorname{Li}_3(3/5) -\frac 18\operatorname{Li}_3(4/5) + \frac 14\operatorname{Li}_3(1/10) - \frac 75\ln(2)\,\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(1/3)+\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1/4)}2 +\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5)+\operatorname{Li}_2(3/5)\right) - \ln(5)\,\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5)+2\operatorname{Li}_2(3/5)\right)$$

---

$$I\left(\frac 12,1\right)=-\frac{39}8\zeta(3)+\left(\ln(2)+5\ln(3)+2\ln(5)\right)\zeta(2)-\frac 5{12}\ln(3)^3+\ln(2)^2\ln(25/8)-\ln(25/9)\ln(5)^2 -\ln(4)\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(1/3)+\frac 34 \operatorname{Li}_2(1/4)\right)-(\ln(4)+2\ln(5))\;(\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5)+\operatorname{Li}_2(3/5))+\frac 12\operatorname{Li}_3(1/3)+2\operatorname{Li}_3(2/3)$$

---

$$I\left(\frac 13,1\right)=-\frac{139}{24}\zeta(3)+\left(\frac 94\ln(2)-\frac 5{12}\ln(3)+\frac 13\ln(5)\right)\pi^2 + 2\ln(2)^2\ln(5) - 2\ln(2)^3 -\frac 23\ln(3)^3 - 2\ln(5)^3  + 2\ln(3)\ln(5)^2 + 2\operatorname{Li}_3(1/3) + 2\operatorname{Li}_3(2/3) - 2\ln(2)\,\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(1/3)+\frac 12\operatorname{Li}_2(1/4)+\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5) +\operatorname{Li}_2(3/5)\right) - 2\ln(5)\;(\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5)+\operatorname{Li}_2(3/5))$$

---

$$I\left(\frac 23,1\right)=\frac{573}{128}\zeta(3)+\left(\frac{31}{64}\ln(2)-\frac 23\ln(3)-\frac 5{48}\ln(5)\right)\pi^2 + \frac {47}{32}\ln(2)^3 + \frac 34\ln(3)^3 + \frac {79}{32}\ln(5)^3 - 3\ln(2)\ln(5)^2 + \frac{45}{32}\ln(2)^2\ln(5) - \frac 74\ln(3)\ln(5)^2 - \frac 54\operatorname{Li}_3(1/3) - \frac 94\operatorname{Li}_3(2/3) - \frac {17}{32}\operatorname{Li}_3(1/5) - \operatorname{Li}_3(1/6) - \frac {13}8\operatorname{Li}_3(2/5) - \operatorname{Li}_3(3/5) - \frac {27}{32}\operatorname{Li}_3(4/5) - \frac 5{16}\operatorname{Li}_3(1/10) + \ln(2)\,\left(\frac 54\operatorname{Li}_2(1/3) + \frac 58\operatorname{Li}_2(1/4)\right) + (\ln(3)-\ln(2))\operatorname{Li}_2(1/5) + \frac{3\ln(2)+7\ln(5)}4\,(\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5) + \operatorname{Li}_2(3/5))$$

---

$$I\left(\frac 14,1\right)=\frac{335}{32}\zeta(3)-\left(\frac{95}{48}\ln(2)+\frac 23\ln(3)+\frac 1{24}\ln(5)\right)\pi^2 + \frac {107}{24}\ln(2)^3 + \frac 73\ln(3)^3 + \frac {41}8\ln(5)^3 - \ln(2)\ln(5)^2 - \frac{21}8\ln(2)^2\ln(5) - \frac {11}2\ln(3)\ln(5)^2 - 7\operatorname{Li}_3(1/3) - \frac{11}2\operatorname{Li}_3(2/3) - \frac 78\operatorname{Li}_3(1/5) + \operatorname{Li}_3(2/5) - \frac 32\operatorname{Li}_3(3/5) + \frac 38\operatorname{Li}_3(4/5) - \frac 32\operatorname{Li}_3(1/6)- \frac 54\operatorname{Li}_3(1/10) + \ln(2)\;\left(4\operatorname{Li}_2(1/3) + 2\operatorname{Li}_2(1/4) + \frac 54\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5) + \frac {13}4\operatorname{Li}_2(3/5)\right) + \frac {19}4\ln(5)\;\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(2/5) + \operatorname{Li}_2(3/5)\right)$$

---

Raw expressions for (*the much needed*) simplifications and manipulations
($I(4,1),I(5,1),I(1/2,1),I(1/3,1),I(2/3,1),I(1/4,1)$ respectively)

```
- 1915/128*zeta(3)+(359/192*ln(2) + 2*ln(3) + 175/96*ln(5))*PI^2 +(513/32*ln(2)^2*ln(5) - 1535/96*ln(2)^3 - 15/4*ln(3)^3 - 1031/96*ln(5)^3 - 31/8*ln(2)*ln(5)^2  + 93/8*ln(3)*ln(5)^2 + 45/4*polylog(3, 1/3) +93/8*polylog(3, 2/3) - 81/32*polylog(3, 1/5) - 3/8*polylog(3, 1/6) - polylog(3, 2/5) - 3/8*polylog(3, 3/5) - 91/32*polylog(3, 4/5) + 5/16*polylog(3, 1/10) - 12*ln(2)*polylog(2, 1/3) - 8*ln(2)*polylog(2, 1/4) - 2*ln(2)*polylog(2, 1/5) - 163/16*ln(2)*polylog(2, 2/5) - 195/16*ln(2)*polylog(2, 3/5) - 189/16*ln(5)*polylog(2, 2/5) - 189/16*ln(5)*polylog(2, 3/5))

- 577/160*zeta(3) +(191/240*ln(2)+11/15*ln(3)-11/60*ln(5))*PI^2 + 17/10*ln(3)*ln(5)^2 - 17/30*ln(3)^3 - 173/960*ln(4)^3 - 181/120*ln(5)^3  - 1/10*ln(4)*ln(5)^2 + 51/160*ln(4)^2*ln(5) + 2*polylog(3, 1/3) + 7/5*polylog(3, 2/3) - 3/8*polylog(3, 1/5) + 9/10*polylog(3, 2/5) - 3/5*polylog(3, 3/5) - 1/8*polylog(3, 4/5) + 1/4*polylog(3, 1/10) - 7/10*ln(4)*(polylog(2,1/3)+polylog(2,1/4)/2+polylog(2,2/5)+polylog(2,3/5)) - ln(5)*polylog(2, 2/5) - 2*ln(5)*polylog(2, 3/5)

-39/8*zeta(3)+(ln(2)+5*ln(3)+2*ln(5))*zeta(2)-5/12*ln(3)^3+ln(2)^2*ln(25/8)-ln(25/9)*ln(5)^2 -ln(4)*(polylog(2,1/3)+3/4*polylog(2,1/4))- (ln(4)+2*ln(5))*(polylog(2,2/5)+polylog(2,3/5))+polylog(3,1/3)/2+2*polylog(3,2/3)

-139/24*zeta(3)+(9/4*ln(2)-5/12*ln(3)+1/3*ln(5))*PI^2 + 2*ln(2)^2*ln(5) - 2*ln(2)^3 -2/3*ln(3)^3 - 2*ln(5)^3  + 2*ln(3)*ln(5)^2 + 2*polylog(3,1/3) + 2*polylog(3, 2/3) - 2*ln(2)*(polylog(2, 1/3)+polylog(2, 1/4)/2+polylog(2, 2/5) +polylog(2, 3/5)) - 2*ln(5)*(polylog(2,2/5)+polylog(2, 3/5))

573/128*zeta(3)+(31/64*ln(2)-2/3*ln(3)-5/48*ln(5))*PI^2 + 47/32*ln(2)^3 + 3/4*ln(3)^3 + 79/32*ln(5)^3 - 3*ln(2)*ln(5)^2 + 45/32*ln(2)^2*ln(5) - 7/4*ln(3)*ln(5)^2 - 5/4*polylog(3, 1/3) - 9/4*polylog(3, 2/3) - 17/32*polylog(3, 1/5) - polylog(3, 1/6) - 13/8*polylog(3, 2/5) - polylog(3, 3/5) - 27/32*polylog(3, 4/5) - 5/16*polylog(3, 1/10) + ln(2)*(5/4*polylog(2,1/3) + 5/8*polylog(2, 1/4)) + (ln(3)-ln(2))*polylog(2, 1/5) + (3*ln(2)+7*ln(5))/4*(polylog(2, 2/5) + polylog(2, 3/5))

335/32*zeta(3)-(95/48*ln(2)+2/3*ln(3)+1/24*ln(5))*PI^2 + 107/24*ln(2)^3 + 7/3*ln(3)^3 + 41/8*ln(5)^3 - ln(2)*ln(5)^2 - 21/8*ln(2)^2*ln(5) - 11/2*ln(3)*ln(5)^2 - 7*polylog(3, 1/3) - 11/2*polylog(3, 2/3) - 7/8*polylog(3, 1/5) + polylog(3, 2/5) - 3/2*polylog(3, 3/5) + 3/8*polylog(3, 4/5) - 3/2*polylog(3, 1/6)- 5/4*polylog(3, 1/10) + ln(2)*(4*polylog(2, 1/3) + 2*polylog(2, 1/4) + 5/4*polylog(2, 2/5) + 13/4*polylog(2,3/5)) + 19/4*ln(5)*(polylog(2, 2/5) + polylog(2, 3/5))
```

Comment: Can you do $I\left(\frac23,1\right)$?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: yes it works (I'll update my answer later).

Comment: It seems incredible.. How did you find these expressions?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: I updated my answer. Concerning the more general $I(a,1)$ a generating function for the fractions $5/2,17/54,257/2250,8933/154350,309817/8930250,18242179/792410850$ should allow to conclude (I think...)

Comment: @Ant: that's pslq (or LLL) at work! Compute a value to high precision (say $400$ digits), conjecture a vector of expressions like $[\ln(3)^3, \ln(3)\ln(2)^2,\zeta(3)]$ and so on and the software will use an [integer relation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) to return you the wished integer coefficients like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108510/approximation-of-e-using-pi-and-phi/108520#108520).

Comment: That $\dfrac14$ looks so lonely there... He's searching for his brother, $\dfrac34$ , and he's all sad, and crying... :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian: since you propose... Yes! you may update it ! :-) (I'm not sure it works in this case but...)

Comment: @Lucian: unfortunately $I(3/4,1)$ has coefficients outside of my table (unknown) so that more work would be required in this case ($I(1/5,1)$ on the other side works but I'll have to let place for more general answers!). Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Ah, I see, thank you. But wouldn't that only give you a value which is close enough? How do you show that the equality indeed holds? I mean it's very interesting but if it's not an equality then it's like writing e with linear combination of $\phi$ and $\pi$ (up to some specified digit of course).. not that useful after all :)

Comment: @Ant: Of course without a proof you can't be sure but I could challenge you to disprove them! :-) This should be easy by increasing the precision but the neat thing about the integer relation algorithms is that you will get the *same* constants by increasing the precision once you crossed the minimal threshold while in my link the constants will change rather randomly with the number of digits (the total count of digits staying near the fixed precision). Of course this could be an illusion with a second threshold much higher and so on (like when playing with $\theta$ functions).

Comment: @Ant: anyway I am trying another experimental path and, should you have a generating function for $5/2,17/54,257/2250,8933/154350,309817/8930250,18242179/792410850,\cdots$, then I could give you a (still not proved) formula for  $I(a,1)$. Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I see, thank you for the explanation. This is a very interesting approach! I'd love to study it a bit better in the future. :-)

Comment: @Ant: You may try with this [paper](http://www.ams.org/notices/200505/fea-borwein.pdf) by Bailey and Borwein (experimental mathematics is fun !).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you for the reference! I'll take a look at it! :)